# ng-hide and ng-show with a counter angularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm trying to hide a < li > and show another with angularjs.
I have a counter that when is 0, it displays one < li > and when is 1 or higher, display another < li >.

HTML

```
<li ng-hide="getDatosMiro.dataOut({{contadorMiro}} != 0)"><a ng-click="getAlerts();$event.stopPropagation()" href="#"><img src="/NeoSANUKCRMWebProfile/static/img/u1823.png" /></a> <span>MIRO Cases <span class="exclamation">! <span class="badge" ng-controller="miroControler">{{contadorMiro}}</span></span></span></li>
<li ng-hide="getDatosMiro.dataOut({{contadorMiro}} == 0)"><a ng-click="getAlerts();$event.stopPropagation()" href="#"><img src="/NeoSANUKCRMWebProfile/static/img/u1823.png" /></a> <span style="color:#000;">MIRO Cases </span></li>
```

ANGULAR

```
var app = angular.module('angularRoutingApp');
app.controller('miroControler', ["$scope","getDatosMiro","getCRMCabecera",function($scope,getDatosMiro,getCRMCabecera) {
    $scope.inicializarDatos=function()
    {
        $scope.contadorMiro=0;
        var dataIn=getDatosMiro.dataIn;
        var dataOut=getDatosMiro.dataOut;
        if (getDatosMiro.dataOut !=0)
        {
            alert('datos de entrada');
            var total = getDatosMiro.dataOut.numeroIncidents * 1 + getDatosMiro.dataOut.numeroCompliants * 1
               + getDatosMiro.dataOut.numeroDissatisfactions * 1;

            $scope.contadorMiro=total;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('datos cero');

            //$scope.contadorMiro="-";

            $scope.contadorMiro=ng-show;

        }

    };

    // leer datos de cabecera
    getDatosMiro.checkCompletion('getDatosMiro.done',$scope).then(
        function(event)
        {
            $scope.inicializarDatos();
        });
    //
}]);
```

In HTML I change {{contadorMiro}} by total, change ng-hide by ng-show and I don't know what I have to do in Angular.

Can you help me please, thanx

Comment: Try removing {{}} in ng-hide and ng-show. I think it should be `contadorMiro` and not `{{contadorMiro}}`.

Comment: I remove {{}} but show both < li > not hide anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use services in view, for this you have to use

```
$scope.getDatosMiro = getDatosMiro;
```

You don't need to use `{{}}` to pass params, delete it

```
<li ng-hide="getDatosMiro.dataOut(contadorMiro) != 0)">
```

Comment: I change it, but not hide the < li >, I put the counter to 0 an not hide the list, show me the same line with the counter alert in 0 when this one needs hide and show me another < li >

Comment: I can help you, but I'm not going to do your job. That's not a question.

Answer (score 0):

[ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) work off true and false as stated in the documentation.

So what this means is that you would need to use a variable that is available in scope $scope.contadorMiro  would need to be a number either 0 or 1 based on your calculations.

Amend your html to be  `<li ng-hide="contadorMiro != 0"></li>` and `<li ng-hide="contadorMiro == 0"></li>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Try it, but only show me the first < li > with the counter 0, like this "Miro Cases 0", not hide this line and show me the other one "Miro Cases" without the counter

Comment: only show me this line <li ng-hide="contadorMiro == 0"><a ng-click="getAlerts();$event.stopPropagation()" href="#"><img src="/NeoSANUKCRMWebProfile/static/img/u1823.png" /></a> <span>MIRO Cases <span class="exclamation">! <span class="badge" ng-controller="miroControler">{{contadorMiro}}</span></span></span></li>